# Is ContenType name field always a 1:1 match with Model._meta.verbose_name?

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

Is ContenType `name` field always a 1:1 match with `Model._meta.verbose_name` ?

I know the possibility of using `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance_of_some_class)` for getting instance of ContenType, but I have to do it for whole model, so I would like to have some reliable way of doing it.

Comment: get_for_model can take a instance or a class, so you can use ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Blog) etc? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly. Was not aware of. Thanks! In fact you can put it as the answer if you fullfill info about equality of mentioned fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_for_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model) can take an instance *or* a class, so you can also do the following:

```
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Blog)
```